# Check if JSON key exist in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to check if the key is exist in JSON if it is exist return the whole JSON.

I have a JSON as below:

```
json    
 -------- 
 "fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}] 
 "fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}   
 "fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}  
 "fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]
```

Output: If the JSON ARRAY or JSON Object has key `apples` then return value of key

```
json                                                                    |Output 
 -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
 "fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}]  |[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}]
 "fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}                                 |{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}
 "fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}                                  |{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}
 "fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]                                 | null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '{"fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}]}' as json union all
  select '{"fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}}' union all
  select '{"fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}}' union all
  select '{"fruit":{"pineapples":"5","oranges":"1"}}' union all
  select '{"fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]}' 
)
select json, if(regexp_contains(json, '"apples"'), json_extract(json, '$.fruit'), null) as output 
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I have added one more question. could you please help me :) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573186/extract-value-from-json-array-in-bigquery)

Comment: sure. answered!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `if`:

```
with mytable as (
  select '{"fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}]}' as json union all
  select '{"fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}}' union all
  select '{"fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}}' union all
  select '{"fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]}' 
)
select if(json like '%apples%', json_extract(json, '$.fruit'), null) as output 
from mytable
```

[image]