# Extract value from JSON ARRAY in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract value from JSON ARRAY as below

```
  with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '{"fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10","pear":"20"},
                    {"apples":"5","oranges":"4"},
                    {"apples":"5","oranges":"9","pear":"40"}]}' as json union all
  select '{"fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]}' 
)

select json, if(regexp_contains(json, '"apples":"5"'), (SELECT 
ARRAY_AGG(json_extract_scalar(arr, '$.oranges') ignore nulls)
from 
UNNEST(json_extract_ARRAY(json, '$.fruit')) as arr ), null) as oranges,
if(regexp_contains(json, '"apples":"5"'), (SELECT 
ARRAY_AGG(json_extract_scalar(arr, '$.pear') ignore nulls)
from 
UNNEST(json_extract_ARRAY(json, '$.fruit')) as arr ), null) as pear,
from `project.dataset.table`
```

It gives output as below
[image]

I am expecting output like

| json | oranges | pear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {"fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10","pear":"20"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"9","pear":"40"}]} | 10 | 20 |
|  | 4 | null |
|  | 9 | 40 |
| {"fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]}. | null | null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach with more explicit alignment of respective entries

```
select json, 
  array(
    select 
      if(
        json_extract_scalar(val, '$.apples') = '5',
        struct(
          json_extract_scalar(val, '$.oranges') as oranges,
          json_extract_scalar(val, '$.pear') as pear
        ),
        struct(null, null)
      )
    from t.arr val
  ) fruits
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest([struct(json_extract_array(json, '$.fruit') as arr)]) t
```

It is less verbose and has output of fruits as a repeated record as opposed to two arrays
If applied to sample data in your question  output is

[image]

In case if you really need to keep output is separate columns  - use below

```
select json, 
  array(
    select 
      if(
        json_extract_scalar(val, '$.apples') = '5',
        ifnull(json_extract_scalar(val, '$.oranges'), '0'),
        '0'
      )
    from t.arr val
  ) as oranges,
  array(
    select 
      if(
        json_extract_scalar(val, '$.apples') = '5',
        ifnull(json_extract_scalar(val, '$.pear'), '0'),
        '0'
      )
    from t.arr val
  ) as pear
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest([struct(json_extract_array(json, '$.fruit') as arr)]) t
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you help :) It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

When working with [array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg)

> an error is raised if an array in the final query result contains a
> NULL element.

You can try using a string `'null'` like this:

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '{"fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10","pear":"20"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"9","pear":"40"}]}' as json union all
  select '{"fruit":[{"lettuce":"7","kale": "8"}]}' 
)
select 
  json,
  if( regexp_contains(json, '"apples":"5"'),
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ifnull(json_extract_scalar(arr, '$.oranges'), 'null')) from UNNEST(json_extract_ARRAY(json, '$.fruit')) as arr ),
    ['null']
  ) as oranges,
  if( regexp_contains(json, '"apples":"5"'),
    (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ifnull(json_extract_scalar(arr, '$.pear'), 'null')) from UNNEST(json_extract_ARRAY(json, '$.fruit')) as arr ),
    ['null']
  ) as pear,
from `project.dataset.table`
```

[image]